# Перевести строку с бинарным кодом в изображение

Tags: python, pillow, byte

Новичок. Хотел сделать что бы в моей программе был список картинок в бинарном коде, что бы потом их восстанавливать и использовать.
Нашел вот такой код:

```
from base64 import b64encode as enc64
from base64 import b64decode as dec64
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image


pict = "achiv\\achiv.jpg"
def binary_pic(pict):
    with open(pict, "rb") as f:
        binary = enc64(f.read())
    print(binary)
    return binary

def export(binary):
    image = BytesIO(dec64(binary))
    pillow = Image.open(image)
    x = pillow.show()


export(binary_pic(pict))
```

Переводит изображение в бинарный формат и обратно.
А можно как то перевести в изображение имея строку где записан бинарный код?
К, примеру, после запуска `binary_pic(pict)` я получаю код картинки.
Как можно имея эту строку
`pict = "бинарный код картинки"`
перевести ее в картинку. Потому что насколько я понял значение должны быть, `bytes`
, а не `str`. Если вы знаете как это реализовать на данном примере или есть иной вариант как этого добиться, буду рад если вы поделитесь. Спасибо.

Comment: from PIL import Image

pict = r"achiv\achiv.jpg"
pillow = Image.open(pict)
pillow.show()

Comment: @СергейШ Так это вы просто открываете картинку через PIL, а я спрашиваю можно ли открыть или сохранить картинку если есть ее бинарный код только, без картинки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для перевода `str` в `bytes` следует просто сделать так:

```
bytes("ваш бинарный код", "ascii")
```

Если изображение формата `png` то могут вылетать ошибки связанные с декодированием (дело в том что в png формате могут использоваться символы отсутствующие в таблице ascii). В таком случае стоит писать так

```
bytes("ваш бинарный код", "raw_unicode_escape")
```

Надеюсь, что смог вам помочь!